# how to correctly get inbound message headers with spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I'm receiving email with spring, with a very basic script so far

```
ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("imap.xml");
DirectChannel inputChannel = ac.getBean("receiveChannel", DirectChannel.class);
inputChannel.subscribe(message -> {
    System.out.println(message.getHeaders());
    System.out.println(message.getPayload());

    MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
    String from = (String) headers.get("mail_from");
});
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html#mail-mapping) I thought the headers would get parsed automatically, but the headers I get with the first `System.out.println();` are just

```
{id=c65f55aa-c611-71ee-c56d-6bf13c6f71d0, timestamp=1468869891279}
```

The second output (for `getPayload()`) is

```
org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@6af5615d
```

`from` outputs `null`...

I then tried to use the `MailToStringTransformer`

```
MailToStringTransformer a = transformer();
    a.setCharset("utf-8");
System.out.println(a.transform(message));
```

Which outputs the payload and all the headers I have expected, but (naturally) as a String.

What do I have to do to get the messages headers and text in an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which documentation are you referring, but the current `4.3` version has this:

> By default, the payload of messages produced by the inbound adapters is the raw `MimeMessage`; you can interrogate the headers and content using that object. Starting with version 4.3, you can provide a `HeaderMapper<MimeMessage>` to map the headers to `MessageHeaders`; for convenience, a `DefaultMailHeaderMapper` is provided for this purpose.

And a bit below:

> When you do not provide a header mapper, the message payload is the MimeMessage presented by javax.mail. The framework provides a `MailToStringTransformer`...

If you need some customization on the mapping you always can provide your own `HeaderMapper<MimeMessage>` implementation or `DefaultMailHeaderMapper` extension.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You have quoted the documentation I have linked to. Thank you for that. Can you actually help me? I really don't get how to use the HeaderMapper

Comment: Just try to start from the `DefaultMailHeaderMapper` bean injection into your `imap-idle-channel-adapter`. And also pay attention to the `embedded-parts-as-bytes` option.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was totally wrong before. The problem actually was that I had the wrong version of spring integration and it didn't had the DefaultMailHeaderMapper class. Now it's working