# Get email with raw headers and attachments in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, email, integration, imap

My question based on the topik [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444803/how-to-correctly-get-inbound-message-headers-with-spring-integration)

I also use my own implementation of `DefaultMailHeaderMapper` and I set `embedded-parts-as-bytes = true`.

But I have a problem - I can't get email message attachments.

I get message, but I can't get attachments, because, as I can see from log, attachments don't have boundaries (for example I attach .gitignore file to mail) and, as a result, MimeMessage parser doesn't see attachments:

```
A15 FETCH 291 (BODY.PEEK[HEADER])
* 291 FETCH (BODY[HEADER] {860}
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="=-Kj0VeCHE3Jjjhv1T0WeN"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-Id: <1533397403.64233522.exgaq3po@frv34.fwdcdn.com>
X-Mailer: mail.ukr.net 5.0
To: Pasha <xxx@ukr.net>
From: =?UTF-8?b?0J/QsNCy0LXQuw==?= <xxx@ukr.net>
Date: Sat, 04 Aug 2018 18:43:37 +0300
Received: from [10.10.80.11] (helo=frv197.fwdcdn.com) by frv34.fwdcdn.com; Sat, 04 Aug
2018 18:43:37 +0300
Received: from xxx@ukr.net by frv34.fwdcdn.com;    Sat, 04 Aug 2018 18:43:37 +0300
Received: from [10.10.10.34] (helo=frv34.fwdcdn.com)
by frv197.fwdcdn.com with smtp ID 1flyiP-000B5t-US
for xxx@ukr.net; Sat, 04 Aug 2018 18:43:37 +0300
Subject: test3
Return-path: <xxx@ukr.net>
)
A15 OK FETCH completed
A16 FETCH 291 (BODY.PEEK[1.MIME])
* 291 FETCH (BODY[1.MIME] {74}
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=-Dw7rk3OclJQtNyghQ2Sv"
)
A16 OK FETCH completed
A17 FETCH 291 (BODY.PEEK[1]<0.16384>)
* 291 FETCH (BODY[1]<0> {374}
--=-Dw7rk3OclJQtNyghQ2Sv
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Length: 2
--=-Dw7rk3OclJQtNyghQ2Sv
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+PHNwYW4gY2xhc3M9InhmbV84MjI2NTc1MSI+PGRpdj48YnIvPjwvZGl2Pjwv
c3Bhbj48L2JvZHk+PC9odG1sPg0K
--=-Dw7rk3OclJQtNyghQ2Sv--
)
A17 OK FETCH completed
A18 FETCH 291 (BODY.PEEK[2.MIME])
* 291 FETCH (BODY[2.MIME] {168}
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=".gitignore"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Id: <asor_1533397403953NSzHs>
Content-Disposition: attachment
)
A18 OK FETCH completed
A19 FETCH 291 (BODY.PEEK[2]<0.172>)
* 291 FETCH (BODY[2]<0> {172}
Ly5pZGVhLw0KLy5zZXR0aW5ncy8NCi9iaW4vDQovdGFyZ2V0Lw0KLmNsYXNzcGF0aA0KLnByb2pl
Y3QNCi5naXRpZ25vcmUNCi9zcmMvbWFpbi9yZXNvdXJjZXMvZW1haWwucHJvcGVydGllcyANCi9u
YnByb2plY3Qv
)
A19 OK FETCH completed
A20 EXAMINE Download
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft $Forwarded)
* 291 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft $Forwarded)]
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1073741835]
A20 OK [READ-ONLY] SELECT completed
A21 CLOSE
A21 OK close completed
```

For example, below I show code without using headerMapper:

```
    * 291 FETCH (BODY[]<0> {1730}
Return-path: <xxx@ukr.net>
Received: from [10.10.80.11] (helo=frv197.fwdcdn.com) by frv34.fwdcdn.com; Sat, 04 
Aug 2018 18:43:37 +0300
Received: from [10.10.10.34] (helo=frv34.fwdcdn.com)
by frv197.fwdcdn.com with smtp ID 1flyiP-000B5t-US
for xxx@ukr.net; Sat, 04 Aug 2018 18:43:37 +0300
Date: Sat, 04 Aug 2018 18:43:37 +0300
From: =?UTF-8?b?0J/QsNCy0LXQuw==?= <yyy@ukr.net>
Subject: test3
To: Pasha <xxx@ukr.net>
X-Mailer: mail.ukr.net 5.0
Message-Id: <1533397403.64233522.exgaq3po@frv34.fwdcdn.com>
Received: from xxx@ukr.net by frv34.fwdcdn.com;
Sat, 04 Aug 2018 18:43:37 +0300
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="=-Kj0VeCHE3Jjjhv1T0WeN" 
--=-Kj0VeCHE3Jjjhv1T0WeN
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=-Dw7rk3OclJQtNyghQ2Sv"
--=-Dw7rk3OclJQtNyghQ2Sv
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Length: 2
--=-Dw7rk3OclJQtNyghQ2Sv
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+PHNwYW4gY2xhc3M9InhmbV84MjI2NTc1MSI+PGRpdj48YnIvPjwvZGl2Pjwv
c3Bhbj48L2JvZHk+PC9odG1sPg0K
--=-Dw7rk3OclJQtNyghQ2Sv--
--=-Kj0VeCHE3Jjjhv1T0WeN
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=".gitignore"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Id: <asor_1533397403953NSzHs>
Content-Disposition: attachment
Ly5pZGVhLw0KLy5zZXR0aW5ncy8NCi9iaW4vDQovdGFyZ2V0Lw0KLmNsYXNzcGF0aA0KLnByb2pl
Y3QNCi5naXRpZ25vcmUNCi9zcmMvbWFpbi9yZXNvdXJjZXMvZW1haWwucHJvcGVydGllcyANCi9u
YnByb2plY3Qv
--=-Kj0VeCHE3Jjjhv1T0WeN--
```

Is it a bug of Spring Integration, or I have to add some configuration? I'm using Spring Integration 4.3.17 and I also had tried this on the 5.0.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

See JIRA for more info: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4299.

Starting with version `5.2` we have introduce `autoCloseFolder` which you can configure on the `MailReceiver` to `false`. That allows together with disabled `headerMapper` you are going to have a full raw `MimeMessage` in the `payload` of produced message. So, you are good to parse attachments downstream whatever it is necessary.

Then you would need to close `Folder` from the `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CLOSEABLE_RESOURCE` if you need.